# Find an integer $N$ such that when $n≥N$, $ \left| U \left( \ln,P_n \right)-\int_1^2 {\ {\ln \left( x \right) }}\,dx \right|<ε\,\,? $

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

With 
$\,U \left( \ln,P_{{n}} \right) =\sum _{i=1}^{n}\ln  \left( 1+{\frac {i}{n}} \right) \frac {1}{n}
$
and
$\,L \left( \ln,P_{{n}} \right) =\sum _{i=1}^{n}\ln  \left( 1+{\frac {i-1}{n}} \right) \frac {1}{n}
$

I get

$$
U \left( \ln,P_{{n}} \right)-L \left( \ln,P_{{n}} \right)={\frac {\ln  \left( 2 \right) }{n}}.
$$

For all $ε>0$, and $\,U \left( \ln,P_{{n}} \right) =\sum _{i=1}^{n}\ln  \left( 1+{\frac {i}{n}} \right) \frac {1}{n}\,\,$, how do I proceed to show that there exists an integer $N$ such that when $n≥N$, when

$$
\left| U \left( \ln,P_n \right)-\int_1^2 {\ {\ln  \left( x \right) }}\,dx \right|<ε\,\,?
$$

All help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log(x)$ is a continuous and bounded function on the interval $(1,2)$, hence it is a Riemann integrable function and 
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left|U(f,P_n)-\int_{1}^{2}\log(x)\,dx\right|=0$$
follows from the very definition of Riemann integrability. Explicit bounds can be derived from the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality), since $\log(x)$ is a concave function on $[1,2]$. In particular:

$$\frac{1}{n}\left[\frac{1}{2}\log(1)+\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\ldots+\log\left(1+\frac{n-1}{n}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\log(2)\right]\leq \int_{1}^{2}\log(x)\,dx $$
and
$$ \int_{1}^{2}\log(x)\,dx \leq \frac{1}{n}\left[\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\ldots+\log\left(1+\frac{n-1}{n}\right)+\log(2)\right]$$
is trivial, hence $U(f,P_n)-\int_{1}^{2}\log(x)\,dx$ is bounded by $\frac{\log(2)}{2n}$ in absolute value.

Comment: DAurizio. After considering Your answer, which at first looked straight forward, I realize I don't fully understand it. Assume we know that $\,U \left( f,P_{{n}} \right) =\sum _{i=1}^{n}\ln  \left( 1+{\frac {i}{n}} \right) \frac {1}{n}$. Now, for $ε>0$, I want to show that there exist an integer $N$, such that when $n≥N$, then $\left| U \left( f,P_n \right)-\int_1^2 {\ {\ln  \left( x \right) }}\,dx \right|<ε\,\,$ holds. In Your answer You reach the conclusion that $U(f,P_n)-\int_{1}^{2}\log(x)\,dx$ is bounded by $\frac{\log(2)}{2n}$. Is that similar to say that $\frac{\log(2)}{2N}<ε\,$?

Comment: @Ludvig: for any $\epsilon>0$, as soon as $N$ is large enough, $\frac{\log 2}{2N}<\varepsilon$ holds.

Comment: why does everbody write $U(f,P_n)$ without mentioning that $f=\log$ you could just write $U(\log,P_n)$...

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. Just recall that

$$L(f,P_n) \le \int _1^2 \ln x\, dx \le U(f,P_n).$$

This says $\int _1^2 \ln x\, dx$ lies in the interval $[L(f,P_n),U(f,P_n)].$ Thus the distance from $\int _1^2 \ln x\, dx$ to the upper end point – and this is what you are estimating – is bounded above by the length of the interval, which, as you found, is $(\ln 2)/n.$ Therefore any $N$ such that $\frac{\ln 2}{N} <\epsilon$ will work.